# CSS: Div boxes overlap each other and hide text. How to "clear" them?

Tags: html, css

I have a small issue with my div boxes that I can’t seem to resolve.

I’m dynamically creating these div boxes:

```
<div id="pagelist">
<div class="pagelist_img"><img src="images/default.gif"></div>
<div class="pagelist_h1">HEADLINE</a></div>
div class="pagelist_excerpt">SUMMARY</div>
</div>
```

Each div box consists as shown of an image on the top, then the headline and a short summary of the post. Now, my problem is that the boxes overlap each other but just enough so the summary part is hidden beneath the image of the div box below it.

Okay, it might be a bit confusing but the point of the line is, that somehow the boxes isn’t separated but are overlapping each other.

My CSS for the pagelist div box is:

```
#pagelist{
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    margin: 0 40px 20px 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;

}

.pagelist_h1 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.pagelist_img{
    clear:both;
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.pagelist_excerpt, .pagelist_excerpt p {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #000000;
    clear:both;
}
```

I hope some have a solution or can point me in the right direction because I've tried for some time now to solve it myself, without any luck. I though it was just a matter of using the **clear:both** tag, but it didn't do anything.

Sincere
- Mestika

Comment: hey Mestika check your markup.. it's kinda messed ;)

Comment: yeah, remove the `</a>` and add a `<` at the beginning of the 4th opening `<div>` tag

Comment: What's the image height? I'm guessing you're overflowing the height you set on your pagelist.

Comment: Hey jswolf, hard to keep myself from hurting myself because it was exactly what was wrong with it - don't know what I was thinking about.

Thanks to everyone else for your help and for the nice tip on clearfix:after, I'm sure that will help me out later on.

Comment: glad it worked out for you ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a clearfix.  Something along the lines of:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
    zoom: 1;     /* triggers hasLayout */
}
```

And modify your markup to be

```
<div id="pagelist" class="clearfix">
```

http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

Also, see the dupes:

- [How to fix IE7 float-clear combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273107/how-to-fix-ie7-float-clear-combination)
- [IE7 Clear Float Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365401/ie7-clear-float-issue)
- [Which clearfix method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227067/which-clearfix-method)
- [ClearFix vs Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373544/clearfix-vs-overflow)
- [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the positioning and clears, as default `<div>`s are block level and should display one under the other.

[Made an example with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/9LVwT/1/).